# simple Exec task in a BuildDef (tfsbuild.proj) in TFS and TeamBuild

Tags: msbuild, exec, task, tfsbuild

This does not work (taken from tfsbuild.proj) when queued in BuildExplorer:

Builddef for WFPApp1
.
.
.
.
  
    
  
.
.
.

but this does (taken from the app1.csproj) and build/rebuild inside the VS IDE

csproj for WFPApp1
.
.
.
  
    
  
.
.
.

in the first example, the build just seems to hang indefinitely until cancelled in the BuildExplorer.  You can view the steps thru the BuildExplorer and see that all targets have completed up to that point.

this seems so simple, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Could you post some more information - the actual MSBuild code, A picture of the build steps?

You say "taken from TFSBuild.proj", but I would expect to see MSBuild syntax and I don't...?